# How to print from iPad to CUPS?

Tags: linux, printing, cups, avahi

I would like to print from an iPad2 to the office printer running on CUPS.  After following a couple of cookbook style cheat sheets, printing from the iPad still does not work. the iPad sees the printer entry I made and offers it as an option, but nothing appears on the queue and there is no printer output.  Local print jobs on the server work, so CUPS recognizes and works with the printer.  Avahi-discover lists the printer and will dump the associated XML file. The server is Ubuntu 10.10.

The procedure used is outlined [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=60740).

[This page](http://www.rho.cc/index.php/linux2/48-misc/104-printing-from-ipad-airprint-via-cups) had a simpler recipe.

Any tips appreciated.

**Edit:**

Today, I disabled the firewall on the server.  Now this message shows up in the CUPS error_log repeatedly when trying to print:

```
E [13/Jul/2011:10:17:15 -0400] Request from "192.168.x.y" using invalid Host: field "server.local"
```

The name of the server is server.local, which can be reached using that name.  The address "192.168.x.y" is that of the iPad.

Comment: Is this actually about Linux? I'm having trouble following it, but I think you're trying to change the iPad configuration, which is an iOS problem. If that's what you're doing you might be better served on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) -- we can migrate it there if you like

Comment: No, it is a Linux issue, CUPS is running on a Linux server.  The iPad uses AirPrint (handled by avahi on the Linux side) to find a printer.  There is no more to it on the iPad side.  The Linux side is having problems submitting the job to CUPS.  That is the crux right now.

Comment: Does anything appear in the logs on the Linux machine when you try to print? (Look at files that get modified in `/var/log` and `/var/log/cups`; post every log message that's produced at the time of your attempt.)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Posting an answer that was edited into the question)</sub>

This is a [bug in CUPS](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=530027). The bug report lists several workarounds:

- Add `ServerAlias *` to `cupsd.conf`
- Add `ServerAlias servername` to `cupsd.conf`
- Add `HostNameLookups On` to `cupsd.conf`